# How to perform unit testing for a particular function in c# desktop application?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have a function named LoadCitation.

```
public void LoadCitation()
    {

        cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from tbl_Users where isLogin=1", con);
        sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        sqlDataAdapter.Fill(ds);
        String username = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["username"].ToString();
        sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select id,title,author1_fname,author1_lname,author2_fname,author2_lname,author3_fname,author3_lname,doctype,year,publisher,abstract,nameofdoc,issue,volume,pgno,url,accessdate,notes,tag from tbl_Citation  where username ='" + username + "'", con);
        DataSet = new DataSet();
        con.Open();
        sqlDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet, "tbl_Citation");
        con.Close();

        dgeviewcitation.DataSource = DataSet;
        dgeviewcitation.DataMember = "tbl_Citation";
    }
```

I want to perform unit testing for this method.

```
[TestClass()]
public class EditcitationTests
{

    [TestMethod()]
    public void LoadCitationTest()
    {

    }
}
```

I have created method but didn't know what to write inside the function for unit testing...

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: What about the method are you trying to test? Once you have that answer, you'll know what to put in the test.

Comment: @SLaks do we not have a canonical question for SQL injection?

Comment: Pick up a book on the subject. Writing good unit tests is a skill like any other skill - you need to learn it. And the code you have written is not testable

Answer (score 1):

As written, this method is not unit testable.

That's because it has a hard dependency on an external resource. What if the test was run in an environment that didn't have that DB set up? How do you know what data will be in the DB? Unit tests should never leave their class (and any mocks).

So first, you need to get that SQL into a service that is injected into your form (also fix the SQL injection vulnerability while you're at it!). Then your test will *mock* that service (using something like `NSubstitute` or `Moq`) and you can verify that the data the mock returns is stored correctly in `dgeviewcitation`.

Note that UIs are usually terrible candidates for unit tests, the correct approach is to have them as a very thin (as thin as possible) layer over your actual logic, and then unit test the logic. Architectural patterns like MVVM try to help with this.